# Tomcat clientAuth="want" removes request certificate and process the request

Tags: tomcat, ssl, soap

I am trying to add a security to my SOAP requests. I want to allow it in two levels: 1. Basic ssl. 2. SSL with a certificate.

I tried to set Server.xml in tomcat to use clientAuth="want" and the results were not as I expected:

When I have a certificate (in tomcat) which doesn't recognize a certificate (in soap), Tomcat simply removes the SOAP certificate (javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate is null) and let my server to process the soap request. Rest works as expected.

Do I have a way to setup Tomcat server so it will block untrusted cerificates but let requests without certificates pass?

My server.xml so far is:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="want" keystoreFile="${user.home}/<some>.keystore" keystorePass="<some pass>" 
maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" truststoreFile="${user.home}/<some>.keystore" truststorePass="<some pass>"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you already have what you want:  reject client with untrusted certificate and accept client without any certificate. I do not understand your question.

Comment: When client comes with untrusted certificate it doesn't block him!! It only removes the certificate from client header... My problem is that i want to check the certificate in my server code and i cant because it is removed in "want" mode and client is totally blocked in "true" mode.

Comment: I see your point now. Strange. Probably I cannot help you. Maybe try to use different http protocol version? `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, somehow i needed to add to the startup.bat file:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%CLIENT_CERT% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<pasword>
```

Then it worked.